# Templated Tokenizer Functions

Tags: c++, parsing

I wanted to be able to tokenize a few different containers so I created a generic way to do it. I originally wrote this in Visual Studio 2012, but I had to modify it to get it to compile on Ideone.

Here is a brief description of my tokenizer functions:

`Tokenize ()`: Tokenizes a container based on a single delimiter.

`TokenizeIf ()`: Tokenizes a container based on a single delimiter and a condition.

`BackInsertTokenize ()` and `BackInsertTokenizeIf ()`: Wrapper for containers that can use a `std::back_inserter` iterator.

A specialized `BackInsertTokenize ()` for character types (`char`, `wchar`, etc).

Here are my generic tokenizer functions:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

template <typename Token, typename Iter, typename OutIter, typename Condition>
auto TokenizeIf (Iter begin, Iter end, OutIter out, typename std::iterator_traits <Iter>::value_type delimiter, Condition condition) -> OutIter
{
    if (begin == end) {
        return out ;
    }

    auto current = begin ;
    auto next = begin ;

    do {
        next = std::find (current, end, delimiter) ;
        Token token (current, next) ;

        if (condition (token) == true) {
            *out++ = std::move (token) ;
        }
        current = next ;

    } while (next != end && ++current != end) ;

    if (next != end) {
        Token token ;
        if (condition (token) == true) {
            *out++ = std::move (token) ;
        }
    }

    return out ;
};

template <typename Token, typename Iter, typename OutIter>
auto Tokenize (Iter begin, Iter end, OutIter out, typename std::iterator_traits <Iter>::value_type delimiter) -> OutIter
{
    if (begin == end) {
        return out ;
    }

    auto current = begin ;
    auto next = begin ;

    do {
        next = std::find (current, end, delimiter) ;
        *out++ = Token (current, next) ;
        current = next ;

    } while (next != end && ++current != end) ;

    if (next != end) {
        *out++ = Token () ;
    }

    return out ;
};

template <class ContainerOut, class ContainerIn, class Condition>
auto BackInsertTokenizeIf (ContainerIn const &in, typename ContainerIn::value_type delimiter, Condition condition) -> ContainerOut
{
    typedef typename ContainerOut::value_type Token ;

    ContainerOut out ;
    TokenizeIf <Token> (std::begin (in), std::end (in), std::back_inserter (out), delimiter, condition) ;
    return out ;
}

template <class ContainerOut, class ContainerIn>
auto BackInsertTokenize (ContainerIn const &in, typename ContainerIn::value_type delimiter) -> ContainerOut
{
    typedef typename ContainerOut::value_type Token ;

    ContainerOut out ;
    Tokenize <Token> (std::begin (in), std::end (in), std::back_inserter (out), delimiter) ;
    return out ;
}

template <class ContainerOut, class CharT>
auto BackInsertTokenize (const CharT *in, CharT delimiter) -> ContainerOut
{
    typedef typename ContainerOut::value_type Token ;

    ContainerOut out ;
    Tokenize <Token> (in, in + std::char_traits<CharT>::length (in), std::back_inserter (out), delimiter) ;
    return out ;
}
```

These are the test cases that I was interested in:

```
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
    std::string const s1 = ",hello,5,cat,192.3," ;
    auto const t1 = BackInsertTokenize <std::vector <std::string>> (s1, ',') ;

    std::vector <char> v1 = {'S', '1', '\0', 'S', '2', 'I', 'N', '\0', 'S', '3', '\0', '\0'} ;
    auto const t2 = BackInsertTokenizeIf <std::vector <std::string>> (v1, '\0', [] (const std::string &s) {
        return !s.empty () ;
    }) ;

    auto const t3 = BackInsertTokenize <std::vector <std::string>> ("C:\\Some\\Path\\To\\Nowhere", '\\') ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code generally looks good to me.  It is clear, complete and working.  The naming and formatting are clear and consistent (although I prefer to read code that does not have the space before each statement-terminating semicolon) but I did see a few things that may help you improve your code.

### Consider using `{}` style initializers

There are a few places where  a `Token` is constructed, such as this:

```
Token token (current, next_) ;
```

However, this *might* be misconstrued as a function call. Assuming that you're using C++11 or better, it may be worth considering using the `{}` style for the constructor:

```
Token token {current, next} ;
```

This can't be misconstrued as a function call and may be slightly less ambiguous.

### Consider alternative usage

The code works well for the use cases you've said you're interested in addressing.  That's good, and it may be all you ever need, but when I first saw the code, I thought it might be useful to be able to use it like this:

```
std::string const s2 = "55,33,1,7,42";
auto const t4 = BackInsertTokenize <std::vector <int>> (s2, ',') ;
```

The intent was to create a vector of integers from the `const` string, but this code doesn't actually compile.  The problem is essentially this line:

```
*out++ = Token (current, next) ;
```

That works fine for any `Token` type that can be constructed from an iterator range like this, but not for a primitive type like `int`.  One way to address that might be to provide another template that additionally takes an operator to explicitly perform this conversion with the given types.

### Omit `return 0`

When a C++ program reaches the end of `main` the compiler will automatically generate code to return 0, so there is no reason to put `return 0;` explicitly at the end of `main`.

Comment: You make a great point about alternative usage. Does omitting `return 0` work on older (non-C++11) compilers?

Comment: Yes, the implicit `return 0` was added to the C standard in 1999 and to the C++ language around the same time.